# Guess Who Am I?

Tags: riddle

If you look you cannot see me. And if you see me you cannot see anything else. I can make anything you want happen, but later everything goes back to normal. Guess What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> your fantasy?

You can make happen anything then, and are limited to what you see at that moment.

Comment: Yeah! But please remove the comment, so others are not spoiled :P

Comment: @pacoverflow Imagination and DAY DREAM both are different thing...

Comment: yeah because daydreaming involves no imagination whatsoever....

Answer (score 4):

Could you be:

> **A Dream**. You can't see your dreams when you are awake and 'looking', and when you are asleep and dreaming you can't 'look' to see anything else. In a dream you can be able to control what happens (Lucid dreaming), but once you wake up, everything is back to 'normal' (reality).

Comment: Quite near to answer buddy !!!

Comment: ANSWER IS NOT A DREAM

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Mark's answer:

> A daydream.

Because:

> We can't really see daydreams, but when we daydream, we don't really see anything else. We daydream about what we want, but then get snapped back to reality.

Comment: Dammit, ninja'd! :-)

Comment: Of course I would upvote this, but I've already used up all my votes for today!

Comment: Nope ... You are Quite near to ANSWER BUDDY !!!

Answer (score 3):

In a similar vein to Mark N's answer, how about

> a DAYDREAM?

*If you look you cannot see me. And if you see me you cannot see anything else. I can make anything you want happen, but later everything goes back to normal.*

> If you look at the real world, you can't see your daydreams. If you 're living in a daydream, you can't see what's really going on. Anything can happen in a daydream, but when you snap out of it, life is normal again.

Comment: Nope ... You are Quite near to ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> the inside of your eyelids? You can't see them when "looking", and you can't see anything else while you can see them. The visual deprivation makes it easier to imagine/see your fantasies!

Comment: nope ... wrong answer

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please could you add some explanation as to why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: +1 because that was my first thought as well and it's the only answer here that isn't in the same vein.

Answer (score 0):

> A dream.
> When you look, you open your eyes and the dream ends.  When you *are* dreaming, you can't see anything else, as your eyes are closed.  Anything can happen in a dream and when it's over, it's back to dull reality.

Comment: Nope ...Not a DREAM !!!  you are quite near!

Comment: Imagination?  I can't see how you can improve on "dream", as it fits all your riddle criteria.  You should consider it as a valid answer.